# Add value to specific cell based on column & row values

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to add a value, EmmaBalance into a cell in the same row as Emma & the same column as Account Balance. I'm able to find the row and column which I've labelled c & d and I have the value 'Emma Balance' but I'm not sure how to add value to the correct cell. For example, if Account Balance is Column B & Emma is Row 3, I want value to add to Cells(3, 2). Here's what I have so far:

```
Sub FindAccBal()

    'Declaring location of January files
    Dim JanFile As String
    Dim Janwb As String
    Dim rt As String
    
    'Declaring account balances for each case manager
    Dim EmmaBalance As Long
    
    'referencing folder locations for January files
    rt = "Z:\testfolder\"
    JanFile = "Dataset.xlsx"
    Janwb = rt & JanFile
    
    'opens the workbook to calculate value
    Workbooks.Open Janwb

    'calculating my value
    EmmaBalance = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Workbooks("Dataset.xlsx").Worksheets("HET DataSet").Range("H:H"), "Emma", Workbooks("Dataset.xlsx").Worksheets("HET DataSet").Range("J:J"))
    
    'finding 'Account Balance' in Row 1, naming it c
    With Worksheets(1).Range("1:1")
    Set c = .Find("Account Balance", LookIn:=xlValues)
    End With
    
    'finding 'Emma' in column A, calling it d
    With Worksheets(1).Range("A:A")
    Set d = .Find("Emma", LookIn:=xlValues)
    End With
    
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This, updated code should tell you if there's a problem with the Finds.

```
Sub FindAccBal()

'Declaring location of January files
Dim JanFile As String
Dim Janwb As String
Dim rt As String
    
    'Declaring account balances for each case manager
Dim EmmaBalance As Long
    
    'referencing folder locations for January files
    rt = "Z:\testfolder\"
    JanFile = "Dataset.xlsx"
    Janwb = rt & JanFile
    
    'opens the workbook to calculate value
    Workbooks.Open Janwb

    'calculating my value
    EmmaBalance = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Workbooks("Dataset.xlsx").Worksheets("HET DataSet").Range("H:H"), "Emma", Workbooks("Dataset.xlsx").Worksheets("HET DataSet").Range("J:J"))
    
    'finding 'Account Balance' in Row 1, naming it c
    With Worksheets(1).Range("1:1")
        Set c = .Find("Account Balance", LookIn:=xlValues)
    End With
    
    If c Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Account Balance not found!"
    Else
        MsgBox "Account Balance found in column " & c.Column
    End If
    
    'finding 'Emma' in column A, calling it d
    With Worksheets(1).Range("A:A")
        Set d = .Find("Emma", LookIn:=xlValues)
    End With
    
    If d Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Emma not found!"
    Else
        MsgBox "Emma found in row " & d.Row
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Seeing the following error: Object Variable or With block variable not set. Run-time error '91'.

Comment: Sounds like one, or both, of the Finds have failed. What happens if you run the code I've added in my answer?

Comment: The finds work okay, I see this error when I added that line of code to the end.

Comment: Yes this helps me find the values but I'm looking to add the value to column of Account Balance, Row of Emma which I still cannot do.